# Jquery Datepicker css or script issue

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I have jQuery Datepicker on my page. When I am selecting value its not working at the same time its added # on URL. I am not understanding this problem. I have done it as follow,

```
$("#AsOfDate").datepicker({
                minDate: new Date(1900, 01, 01),
                maxDate: new Date(),
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
            });
```

Anyone having idea about it.

Comment: see on the console once .Is there any error?

Comment: You should remove the last ',' after changeYear: true since you don't have any options after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#AsOfDate").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    yearRange: '1900:2012',
                    monthRange: '01:12',
                    minDate: new Date('1900/01/01'),
                    maxDate: '+30Y,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="AsOfDate" /></p>


    </body>
    </html>
```

make sure jQuery and Jquery Ui are loading correctly, try loading it from the CDN.